# Django.Вывод отформатированного текста из TextField в шаблон

Tags: python, django

Я зеленый в Django.

Хочу сделать на сайте поле ввода текста пользователем. После чего текст сохраняем в БД. И выводим в шаблон.
***Проблема*** в том, что текст будет сплошняком храниться в моделе без форматирования(хотя бы перенос строки, я уже не говорю про курсив и т.п.) и соответственно выводиться в шаблон сплошным текстом.

***Подскажите*** как решить такую задачу? Как учитывать перенос строки, сделанный пользователем, при выводе в шаблон?

ЗЫ Манипуляции с html в TextField и фильтром safe не подойдет;
BBcode вариант, но тогда встает вопрос как сделать форумную форму ввода текста с кнопками форматирования?

Comment: вопрос с учетом переноса решил через {{ value|linebreaks }}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое простое - использовать любой расширенный редактор текста для django. Например, [django-ckeditor](http://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor). У него есть встроенный field, который поможет вам фильтровать ненужные html теги. Плюс есть и сам html редактор, в базе хранится html. В целом там в справке всё расписано

Второй вариант - использовать пакет [bleach](https://github.com/mozilla/bleach) и вручную фильтровать теги. Его можно также использовать с каким-нибудь дополнением, вроде [markdown](https://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/). Из минусов тут - придётся написать собственный обработчик этих самых тегов. Пример кода:

```
# templatetags/comments.py

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import bleach
import markdown

def markdown_comment(value):
    return bleach.clean(
        markdown.markdown(value, extensions=['nl2br']),
        strip=True,
        tags=['strong', 'p', 'blockquote', 'br'])

@register.filter
def comment_markdown(value):
    return mark_safe(markdown_comment(value))
```

Ну и потом использовать как `{{ value|comment_markdown }}`

Answer (score 0):

Такая же задача была, я воспользовался этим:

```
{{ value|linebreaksbr }}
```

(взято их доков: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaks )

Если только нужен был перенос текста)

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/867825)